# How to calculate total price of order?

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate the total price of an order. In this case the company only sells unique items, they may however have the same broad product description.

These are the relevant tables

**Jewellery**

```
JewelleryID Description                                        Price                  Year        TypeID
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------- ----------- -----------
1           Gold Necklace                                      250                    1925        1
2           Gold Ring                                          340                    1889        3
3           Gold Broach                                        570                    1901        3
4           Diamond Ring                                       2300                   1952        3
5           Pearl Earrings                                     460                    1936        3
6           Pearl Necklace                                     780                    1939        3
7           Diamond Ring                                       1250                   1898        3
11          Gold Watch                                         560                    1905        2
12          Silver Necklace                                    275                    1876        3
13          Gold Broach                                        250                    1949        3
14          Diamond Earrings                                   2500                   1924        3
15          Gold Earrings                                      280                    1939        1
16          Silver Bracelet                                    245                    1946        3
17          Ruby Ring                                          550                    1915        3
18          Silver Watch                                       780                    1936        4
```

**JewellerySales**

```
SaleID      JewelleryID
----------- -----------
1           1
1           7
2           11
3           2
3           12
3           13
4           3
5           13
6           4
6           14
7           5
7           17
8           6
9           15
9           18
```

**Sales**

```
SaleID      CustomerID  SaleDate
----------- ----------- ----------
1           1           2016-06-02
2           2           2016-06-02
3           3           2016-06-03
4           1           2016-06-04
5           4           2016-06-04
6           2           2016-06-06
7           5           2016-06-07
8           6           2016-06-07
9           7           2016-06-08
```

Just looking for any pointers because I am completely lost here.

For example: Sale ID 1 contains two items (JewelleryID 1 and 7). The total price is (250 + 1250) 1500 however I just cannot figure out how to display this for each SaleID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate the prices so they can be joined, then inner join the tables and group by Sale Id:

```
SELECT JewellerySales.SaleID, SUM(Jewellery.Price)
FROM JewellerySales
INNER JOIN Jewellery
ON JewellerySales.JewelleryID=Jewellery.JewelleryID
GROUP BY JewellerySales.SaleID;
```

Comment: Thank you! very helpful.